# How can I render blocks based on array of blocks

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

In my edit function I use BlockEditorProvider to allow a user to add some blocks in defined areas, and parse nested blocks using onChange to store them in the attribute. The end result is something like this

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [clientId] => e69604c9-9f4f-42e9-80c1-591b4e78d1b3
                        [name] => core/columns
                        [isValid] => 1
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [className] => is-style-blue-quotedddddd
                            )

                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [clientId] => 773b2a25-6b77-447e-a78e-0ef295553c40
                                        [name] => core/column
                                        [isValid] => 1
                                        [attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [className] => c-block-tabbed-content
                                            )

                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [clientId] => 411b52d3-d62b-4d90-82d1-d3ec4a77a3b7
                                                        [name] => core/heading
                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [content] => ddddddd
                                                                [level] => 2
                                                                [placeholder] => Title
                                                            )

                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [clientId] => 21d3decd-3eed-4d44-b166-1af2d87b2b2d
                                                        [name] => core/paragraph
                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [content] => 
                                                                [dropCap] => 
                                                                [placeholder] => Description
                                                            )

                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [2] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [clientId] => b523cf91-c760-42b4-84f4-c3f6f6f21f9c
                                                        [name] => core/columns
                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [clientId] => cb3feeb3-3556-486d-bd3c-e9cfb69991d7
                                                                        [name] => core/column
                                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                            )

                                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [0] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [clientId] => 55cce3f6-8228-461f-92ca-ac2fa3375e9a
                                                                                        [name] => core/list
                                                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [ordered] => 
                                                                                                [values] => 
                                                                                            )

                                                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [1] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [clientId] => c4b36656-bb07-4e8a-bb13-0e3af64f1b90
                                                                        [name] => core/column
                                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                            )

                                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [0] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [clientId] => a12fcea7-44a5-4431-b73f-06a1d8b4ca44
                                                                                        [name] => core/list
                                                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                                [ordered] => 
                                                                                                [values] => 
                                                                                            )

                                                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [clientId] => c8a71a68-b32a-4737-97ad-264622b0f2f9
                                        [name] => core/column
                                        [isValid] => 1
                                        [attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [clientId] => 39049805-e22a-4f36-9f91-70e86bc51d14
                                                        [name] => core/image
                                                        [isValid] => 1
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [alt] => 
                                                                [bgPosition] => 
                                                                [bgColor] => 
                                                                [bgHeight] => 50
                                                                [bgWidth] => 50
                                                                [bgGutter] => 25
                                                            )

                                                        [innerBlocks] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                        )
```

Then I am passing this to save function, and I need a way to render these blocks. I know there is innerBlocks component, but that component can be used only once per block, and I have multiple arrays with some content that should be rendered.

<InnerBlocks
template={ TEMPLATE }
/>

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress Developer Guide, the tutorial "[Building a custom block editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor)" seems to be similiar to what you are trying to accomplish with storing blocks in an array.

When saving block data in `onChange()`, the example function `persistBlocks()` stores the array of block content as serialized string in local storage so it can be later edited/parsed, eg:

```
<BlockEditorProvider ... onChange={ persistBlocks }>

function persistBlocks( newBlocks ) {
    updateBlocks( newBlocks );
    window.localStorage.setItem( 'myBlocks', serialize( newBlocks ) );
}
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/tutorial/#saving-block-data

By storing your blocks as a serialized string they will render correctly and be able to be parsed by the Editor with [parse()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/tutorial/#retrieving-previous-block-data) for future editing and keep InnerBlocks where required.

Comment: I need a way to show them in save function, I have them in edit

Comment: @emir In the save function, the serialized representation of the blocks is saved, then the block parser parses the string and displays the content. If you add some standard blocks to a post then save it, then in the Editor look at the code view (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M) you see how the content is saved, so you are just saving the block content into save() and the block parser renders/displays it.

Comment: I need a way to format the output in the save. I have multiple blocks that I should present in tab. I need to map this array and define where will specific code be presented in my html structure at output

Comment: @emir May I suggest looking then at [Dynamic blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/), as they don't implement the javascript save() function and instead use PHP to render/parse the saved array of blocks.  This would then give you complete control over parsing/formatting the saved array and you have access to all the native PHP functions. Is this more like what you're are aiming for?